# How should I prepare a solid wood subfloor for hardwood and ceramic tile flooring?

Tags: flooring

I have a post and beam flooring structure in my 45-year-old home. The subfloor is 2 x 8  tongue and groove installed green. In my remodel, I plan to install 3/4" hardwood flooring over part of my single story home and porcelain tile in the bathroom and laundry room. What type of structure over the 2 x 8's (plywood or OSB)should be installed under each type of new flooring? Additionally, what should the nailing or screwing pattern for that installation?  Tom

Comment: Are you sure it's 2x8? 45 years ago a combination of plywood and particle board was common. Solid wood subfloors had long since gone out of fashion, and two-by subfloor is almost unheard of to begin with, let alone *green*. Where are you?

Comment: Also, how is the subfloor fastened? Does it squeak much?

Comment: To second @isherwood's comments: Are you sure the 2 x 8 floors are not really a hardwood floor that was installed on top of another floor? Have you looked from underneath? (I'm sure you have if you have a standard basement but maybe you have a crawl space, finished basement that hides the underside of your floor, etc.) 2-inch tongue and groove board would be much more normal as a finished floor. I have a solid wood subfloor in my 100-year-old house but it's not tongue and groove, and they are ~10-inch wide planks.

Comment: Timberframe:  What is the spacing between floor supports?  T&G 2x6 will tolerate 4 foot spacing and have allowable deflection.  I wouldn't worry about hardwood directly over the T&G if the floor is flat enough.  Tile:  Do deflection checks first.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford: Can you describe steps to do a deflection test please?

Comment: Deflection calculator here:  https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/deflecto.pl  This seems to be what people use.  Note:  While L/720 is the recommendation for stone, I like to use that for anything involveing large tiles too.

Comment: Search on the tile forums for actual ways to measure.  Most common is to stretch a TIGHT mason line between two 3/4" thick blocks across the room, put a drum on the floor and fill it with water.  Measure the height of the string before and after filling the tank.  If you have access to the underside of the floor, putting a dial indicator against the floor (measures movement to the nearest .001" is easier.